# How do I change the transform:translate css rule according to the screen resolution?

Tags: javascript, css, screen-resolution

Below I have this piece of JS code. When the resolution of the screen is between 995px and 1200px, then the css animation of `transform: translate` should be 22%. How can I do this?

CSS code:

```
.to_be_center {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate(-27%, 25%);
}
```

JS code:

```
function resolution() {
    width = window.screen.availWidth;

    if ((width>=995) && (width<1200)){
        document.getElementsByClassName("to_be_center").style.transform= "translateX(14%)"; 
    }
}

resolution();
```

I call the function in body - `<body onload="resolution()">`.

Comment: `<body onresize="resolution()">`  so that it is called on window resize. And for width refer this [Get the size of the screen, current web page and browser window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window)

Comment: Thanks for the correction about body - the resolution is working when I test it with the Toogle Device Tool in Inspector, but I think the problem is in this line `document.getElementsByClassName("to_be_center").style.transform= "translateX(14%)";`

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('') returns an array. `document.getElementsByClassName()[0].style.transform ..`

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a CSS media query, and define for that screen size how .to_be_center should work?

```
@media (max-width: 995px) {
  .to_be_center{
    /*your styles here*/
  }
}
```

more info can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Thank you, but I've already try many times with CSS media queries and didn't work. Also I read that the they didn't match with CSS animations, didn't know why and I headed to try with JS.

Comment: is your css getting overwritten? did you check? can you post your css we can help with that

Comment: `@media screen and (min-width: 995px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .to_be_center{
    position: relative;
    transform: translate(-22%, 25%);
/*    background-color: red;*/
    }
}`
When I try with the background-color works, but no with the animation .

Comment: and the HTML code: `<!Doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", initial-scale=1>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/styles.css"/>...`

Comment: Yes, I have been overwritting it. Thank you for the observation! :)